# c# winforms reading combobox items one by one

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

Let me give you a quick view of my work. I'm working on winforms.

**What I want to do:** I want to select a file and extract particular paragraphs from it, based on selected values that I have in my **combobox**.

**What I did:**

```
private void ExtrctBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //I have another button to select file
        string sourceFile = "", resultFile = "";

        if (sourceFile == null || !(File.Exists(sourceFile)))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please select a file to continue", "File Error");
        }
        else
        {
            sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();      //start the timer
            ExtrctBtn.Enabled = false;

            resultFile = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(sourceFile), "Results_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyMMddHHmmss") + ".txt");
            WriteReport(resultFile);
            sw.Stop();              //stop the timer
        }

private void WriteReport(string dest)
    {
        try
        {
            int n = 0;
            string key = "";
            string[] keys = new string[10];

            Found:
            key = CmboBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
            if (!keys.Contains(key))
            {
                //copy the required data from source file to result file

                if (n < keys.Length)
                    keys[n++] = key;

                DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Select next key", "Continue?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
                if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
                {
                    goto Found;
                }
                else //if (dialogResult == DialogResult.No)
                {
                    goto Finish;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You have already added this Key","Error");
            }

            Finish:
            SaveFile();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.ToString(), "Exception");
        }
   }
```

Everything is working fine. **What I'm unable to do** is, after I select 1st item from the combobox and the copy-paste operation done, I'm unable to select next items. It just goes to **Found** and throws the error messagebox. I don't want to automatically select combobox items. Rather I want it to wait till the user selects another key from the combobox and *based on the key selection, extract the next paragraph*.

I do realize that I'm missing something. But I don't know what! ***What should I do so that the user can select other combobox items when I click yes from the messagebox?*** I can use Threading concept and use Sleep() to wait for few seconds for user input, but I don't think its feasible.

Does anyone has some other idea? Any help appreciated. thanks in advance.

Comment: Really important: do not use `goto`: it just makes your code really hard to read and maintain.

Comment: You never populate `keys`, so the not contains will always be true.

Comment: You know you can just put your whole objects in the combobox, right? All it needs is a ToString function. Then you just cast `SelectedItem` back to its original type and you're done.

Comment: @Richard: I'm populating it with `if (n < keys.Length) keys[n++] = key;`

Comment: @Nyerguds: Yes I know that. I have another function to add items to combobox and its working fine. no problems with it.

Answer (score 0):

(considering your code) for this you must change the selected Item after reading:

```
key = CmboBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
if(CmboBox.SelectedIndex < ComboBox.Items.Length -1)
      CmboBox.SelectedIndex;
```

But however its not a good Idea to use the `CmboBox.SelectedItem` and change it one by one to get its items. You can just loop through all items. a simple for loop would be the best Option, although there might be other ways like Linq, ...

```
for(int i=0; i<ComboBox.Items.Length;i++)
{
     key = ComboBox.Items[i].ToString();
     //rest of your code
}
```

**Update** Considering your comment:

```
DialogResult current = DialogResult.No;
do
{
    key = CmboBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
    DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Select next key", "Continue?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
    if (!keys.Contains(key))
    {
         if (n < keys.Length)
              keys[n++] = key;
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You have already added this Key","Error");
    }
}while(dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes);
```

Comment: But I don't want to select it automatically. I want the user to select the items from the combobox.

Comment: yes but not automatically. I have mentioned it in the body of my query

Comment: I highlighted it.

Comment: how will I use dialogResult outside if loop? It will throw error. Did you mean to assign `current = dialogResult`?

Comment: In either way, it runs into an infinite loop throwing the message: You have already added this Key

Comment: well message box should be out of the if. (i corrected it).

Comment: Yes but still its a local variable. Cant use it in while statement.

Comment: you can, why shouldn't you?

Comment: How can you? Its throwing error. And than whats the use of `current` variable?